# How to deal with temp tables when compiling database project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, data-tier-applications

We just created a solution with multiple data projects. We inherited the system and want to do a database cleanup but when we compile some of the databases we get the error that table, id etc does not exist and it occures where temp tables are created in stored procedures.

Let's say a stored proc creates a temp table and at the end drops it the compiler complains and says that the table does not exist (in the database schema). How can we work around this? Any settings I can't find?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't and don't compile a database project in the .net sense BTW. You run scripts against a database server that does assorted checks.

Comment: maybe I should have mentioned it is a data-tier application project http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240739.aspx "When you build the DAC project, Visual Studio compiles a DAC definition and places it in a DAC package."

Comment: This is quite serious, because aspnet_Membership stored procedures already use this kind of tables. Could you provide me a link to the microsoft connect issue to track its resolution? I know that I can do a workaround by placing the necessary stored procedures in the post generation script

Comment: The [microsoft connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/541701/data-tier-application-build-failed-if-stored-procedures-works-with-temp-tables) claims "Fixed," but I just observed this problem myself in VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug filed in Microsoft Connect on this issue, and there is a workaround suggested: use table variables instead of temporary tables. So, use

```
declare @t table (ID int, Name nvarchar(100) )
insert into @t ...
```

instead of

```
create table #t (ID int, Name nvarchar(100) )
insert into #t ...
drop table #t
```